# Font replacement script for Beta SEs?

Tags: support, user-interface, fonts, scripts

I would like to view Beta sites in Deja Vu Sans font instead of Arial, is there a script for switching the font?

Comment: I guess you should be able to write a userscript for that. On stackapps.com there are already several userscript to "prettify" Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Bart I checked on stackapps before asking the Question but there is no font-substitution script there. Would you like to write a script that does what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Try using Stylish or UserCSS or any other extension for your browser that allows you to override CSS style values for sites you browse.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of Stylish and I have one userstyle installed already that came ready-made from their website. However, I have neither the time nor the inclination to write one from scratch or adapt one. Would you, or another user, be kind enough to do this for me?

Comment: I found [this script](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/150418) on Userscripts.org and edited it to insert "deja vu sans" in place of "sans serif" and deleted the substitution of Courier (New). Unfortunately Wikipedia still appears with Arial and so does Stackexchange, only that the Arial now looks worse than it did before.